# Can we return a table with about 270 columns on snowflake through a stored procedure using sql? Syntax is below

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

Can we return a table in Snowflake using sql as language? What is the correct syntax if possible?

```
create or replace procedure sp()
returns table ()
language sql
as
    $$ 
    declare
    
    accountingMonth :=(select dateadd(month,case when day(current_timestamp())<=10 then -1 else 0 end,dateadd(month,0,date_trunc('month',current_date()))));
    endmonth  :=(select dateadd(month,1,dateadd(month,case when day(current_timestamp())<=10 then -1 else 0 end,dateadd(month,0,date_trunc('month',current_date())))));
    currmonth date default accountingMonth;

        
    
    begin
          
    create or replace temporary table sa as (
        select col1,col2, col3,datecol,....col270
        from table2 
where datecol = :accountingmonth
        );
    end;
      select *  from sa;
         
     $$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to return table from strored procedure using [RESULTSET](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/resultsets.html#examples-of-using-a-resultset)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp()
RETURNS TABLE(col1 INTEGER, ...)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS

  BEGIN
     -- ...
     let RESULTSET DEFAULT (select * from sa);
    RETURN TABLE(res);
  END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Lukasz. But, its throwing this error on the creation of temporary table. 



"SQL compilation error: syntax error line 39 at position 15 unexpected 'or'. syntax error line 39 at position 26 unexpected 'temporary'."

Comment: Edited the code. Declaring and returning resultset erred out with this.
Multiple SQL statements in a single API call are not supported; use one API call per statement instead.

Comment: @ashrayac Could you please do not change question in place? It invalidates already provided answers? The issue is double BEGIN/END block in the code you have provided: `end;
        declare res resultset default (select *  from sa); <--updated
         begin`